# How can we get information whether my application is running in iframe window or normal browser window in my php code?

Tags: php, iframe

I need to know, whether my php code (apptlication) is running with in iframe window or normal window?

Please help me
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: PHP doesn't know anything about client-windows or frames, by this it cannot get any details about them. Javascript can tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot in PHP as that's only knowable on the client side.

With javascript;

```
if (top === self) {
  // not in any kind of frame
} else {
  // in a frame
}
```

Then you can break-out of the frame with a reload (or report something back to your php application if that's what your after)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that server-side (php). It's possible in client-side (javascript):

```
if (window.location.href != window.top.location.href)
{
  // it is running inside a frame. Force it to run in the full window
  window.top.location.replace(window.location.href);
}
```